# Delays/inconsistencies in AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been working on a web app that allows users to submit content and have that content, and today I've been seeing some unexpected results without making any significant changes.

The basic functionality of the app is that the user submits some POST data from a form on a web page `index.php`, whereupon a PHP script `submit.php` is run to add the data to a table in a database.  Meanwhile, a Jquery function on `index.php` is refreshing the contents of a div with rows selected from the table by means of a script `load.php`, and the function is called once per second.

The problem is that today, suddenly, I'm seeing long (10-20 minute) delays between when the data is added to the table and when it shows up in the Jquery-refreshed div.  Moreover, the div flickers back and forth between its existing contents and the new data set with the added values, as if it were alternating between the realtime results of `load.php` and a previous call to the same script.

I've checked the MySQL database before and after `submit.php` is called and I've verified that the data is being added instantaneously once it's submitted, so the problem has something to do with how the `load.php` script is called from Jquery.

This just started today.  Strangely, I've been seeing this same behavior with another AJAX app that I built earlier to test the same I/O mechanism, and I haven't touched that app's code in over a week.  My system administrator says there haven't been any changes to the server that would account for this.

I've posted all the code to provide all necessary information, but I think the problem is either in `load.php` or the javascript `updateMyContent()` in `index.php`.

`index.php`

```
<script language="JavaScript">

setInterval("updateMyContent();",1000);
$(function(){
    updateMyContent=function(){
        $('#refreshData').load("./module/load.php").fadeIn("slow");
    }
});

</script>

<script language="JavaScript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitForm').on('submit',function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'./module/submit.php',
            data:$('#submitForm').serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $("#success").show().fadeOut(5000);
                $('#textID').val('');
            },
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

</script>



<div style="float: right;
        top: 0;
        " id="submitDiv">
    <form id="submitForm" action="" method="post">
        <textarea id="textID" type="text" name="content" rows=5></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <br>
    <span id="error" style="display: none; color:#F00">error</span>
    <span id="success" style="display:none; color:#0C0">success</span>
</div>
<div style="float: center;" id="refreshData"></div>
```

`submit.php`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['content']))
    {
        $content=$_POST['content'];
        $dsn="mysql:host=someserver.net;dbname=thisdb;charset=utf8";
        $db=new PDO($dsn,'thisdb','password');
        $insertSQL="insert into submission (content) values (?)";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($insertSQL);
        $stmt->execute(array($content));
    }
    else
    {
        echo "FAIL!";
    }
?>
```

`load.php`

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $dsn="mysql:host=someserver.net;dbname=thisdb;charset=utf8";
        $db=new PDO($dsn,'thisdb','password');
        $PDOsql="select * from submission order by id desc";
        $stmt=$db->query($PDOsql);
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $resultRow)
        {
            printf("%s<br>",$resultRow["ID"]);
            printf("%s<br>",htmlspecialchars($resultRow["content"]));
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo "an error occurred!  ".$ex->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you use PHP sessions?

Comment: @EugenRieck, No.  The only persistent connection is what the client maintains with the timed AJAX calls.

Comment: Please retry with a 5 second interval - I have a suspicion concerning overlapping requests, but I am not yet sure enough to write an answer.

Comment: @EugenRieck, strange, I just tested this on a different machine (without changing the interval) and didn't get the flicker.  I suspect it may be how this machine is caching; I'll look into setting up Jquery to suppress caching.

Comment: Or try 2 or 5 seconds on the original machine, you might be walking the thin line, where it works on one machine, but not on another. Best caching supression known to me is adding `nocache=randomBlah(20)` to the query string on GET, but should not be necessary on POST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with it taking so long to return the Ajax response is probably that the table `submissions` has grown. Rather than each second loading all the submissions, append only new submissions to the div. I.e. keep track of the last id received and use this in the query so the where clause is limited.

> Moreover, the div flickers back and forth between its existing contents and the new data set with the added values, as if it were alternating between the realtime results of load.php and a previous call to the same script.

Ajax response can be cached by the browser just like anything else.  To prevent that, you can:

1. Put no-cache headers in the page that processes the request to prevent browser caching of the Ajax responses.  IE is particularly stubborn and will require the most forceful headers.
2. Add a parameter to your Ajax request that is a random number, to make every request unique.
3. Tell JQuery to prevent caching (it just does #2 for you). Use `$.ajaxSetup ({ cache: false  });` or add the `cache: false,` attribute to each call to `$.ajax`

Comment: I went with adding a date stamp as a parameter of the `load.php` call.